# how to access DB retrieved data out of Recordset in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, database, ms-access, recordset

HTML <--------JavaScript-----------> MS Access.

In my below DB connection, I can access DB retrieved data with in Recordset.
But I cant access values out of rs.

```
var cn_dub = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var str1_dub="P:\\Mydb.mdb";
var strConn_dub = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = "+str1_dub+";"; 
cn_dub.Open(strConn_dub); 
var rs_dub = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 
var SQL ="select * from table1";
rs_dub.Open(SQL, cn_dub);
while (!rs_dub.EOF ) { 
    StatusCode_arr_db = rs_dub("statusCode");   
                alert("1-->"+StatusCode_arr_db);    
    rs_dub.MoveNext();      
}
alert("2-->"+StatusCode_arr_db);
rs_dub.Close();
cn_dub.Close();
```

Now alert("2-->"+StatusCode_arr_db); --> having empty value. 
But alert("1-->"+StatusCode_arr_db); --> having value

how can I get value in alert("2-->"+StatusCode_arr_db);

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

based on comment:

```
var StatusCode_arr_db;

while (!rs_dub.EOF ) { 
    StatusCode_arr_db = rs_dub("statusCode");   
                alert("1-->"+StatusCode_arr_db);    
    rs_dub.MoveNext();      
}

alert("2-->"+StatusCode_arr_db);
```

IF you still see the variable as UNDEFINED then do what I say below, BECAUSE I was correct with my ORIGINAL answer.

try

```
 rs_dub["statusCode"];
```

or

```
 rs_dub.Fields("statusCode").value;
```

I believe you were looking at a jscript example (which is MS javascript, not the same.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
But My issue is " I am not able to access the value of the variable 'StatusCode_arr_db' out of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a reference saved on

```
StatusCode_arr_db = rs_dub("statusCode");.
```

However, you can workaround this behaviour with force value to string, e. g.

```
StatusCode_arr_db = rs_dub("statusCode") + "";
```